# Archive Documents from Multiple Libraries

Tags: document-archiving

I have a Sharepoint Page with Multiple Document Libraries.  Is there a way to archive documents after the status column changes to archive for each document residing in the different libraries on that SharePoint Page?  I was looking for some help with possibly using a workflow for the entire page.

Comment: Define archive... move to a different library or folder? Hide from the current view? Move outside of SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to implement this.

1. Create site scheduled workflow. Workflow will check status of documents in documents library and will move documents to archive.
2. Create custom timerjob that will do the same.
3. Create event receiver for each document library. Event receiver will immediately move documents when status changed to 'archive'.